# I have network problems with kubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, kubuntu

I recently installed kubuntu and for some reason its not picking up on my wireless network. Im sort of new at this so please try to keep it as simple as possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that my answer will definitely work but you can give it a try. Actually the wireless problem has become a common problem, and it happened with me too when I installed Kubuntu 12.04. Here is what I did to make it working:

1. First connect with any wired Internet connection or USB Dongle; It will be needed to download the drivers and it is only one time work.
2. Open terminal by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>and execute this command:

   ```
   sudo jockey-kde
   ```

   this application will search for all available drivers and try to download and install if missing.
3. Once successfully finished, you'll get that some wireless drives has been installed. Just restart your system once.

Hope it works for you too. Reply what happens!

Comment: ok so i typed the command into the terminal exactly how you have it but it keeps saying command not found...

Comment: @user268870: My mistake.. In Kubuntu its `jockey-kde`. So replace with this name and then try.. If `jockey-kde` is not installed you can install it by `sudo apt-get install jockey-kde` :) I've also edited my answer.. :)